# Laravel redirection not working after session expires

Tags: php, session, redirect, laravel, authentication

Currently if I am idle in my webapp for long enough my session expires.  When interacting again, I receive an error screen notifying me of the session timeout rather than redirecting me to the homepage.

In my routes.php file I am using this:

```
Route::filter('authenticate', function() {
    if ( !Session::has('user') && Session::get('user')->id ) { // return true if user not logged
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
});
```

Is my logic wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression will never evaluate to true.  You are basically saying this in english:

> If there is no value in the session with the key of 'User', and the session value with the key of user has an id, then do ...

Either there is a session value that has a key of `'User'` or not, but you can't have it both ways.  I think you want to say something like this instead:

```
if ( !Session::has('user') || !Session::get('user')->id )
```

This will execute the redirect under two circumstances:

1. When there is no session value underneath the key of 'user', *or*
2. When the id parameter of the value in the 'user' session value evaluates to false

Comment: For some reason your solution kept redirecting upon logging in, but it did work with just if ( !Session::has('user') )

Comment: that would make sense if the entry in the user key didn't have a value in the `id` property that evaluated to true